# Checkbox validation with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

As part of learning LINQ, i got stuck up with the following problem.

A windows form with N number of Checkboxes and a button. The button should be enabled only when, the user checks\selected any two checkboxes. I am trying to implement this using LINQ, but couldn't achieve the desired results.

I used the following code, but works only when any one of the Checkbox is selected.

```
btnAgree.Enabled = (from chkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox).Any(b => b.Checked);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btnAgree.Enabled = (from chkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox).Count(b => b.Checked) >= 2;`

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
btnAgree.Enabled = ((from chkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox where chkbox.Checked = true).Count >= 2)
```

Comment: As far as I know, `where` should come before `select`, and anyway `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` is enough - there is no need for all the `from` syntax.

Comment: When I used you code after correcting the where clause, I came to learn a new method to set checked property to true through LINQ. Thanks for that :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please also note that I answered just before System.Exception ;)

Answer (score 0):

Count can return the number of checked Checkboxes:

```
btnAgree.Enabled = (from chkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox).Count(b => b.Checked) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the Linq expression to return true if and only if exactly **2** checkboxes are selected?

If so, this should do the trick:

```
btnAgree.Enabled = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                           .Count(b => b.Checked) == 2;
```